# Moving table row from one table to the other using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <!-- Table row trHeader should be here based on a flag //-->  
</table>
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr id="trHeader">
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a flag (essentially a button), that I use to be able to move the table row with id="tbl2". How would I switch it back to the same position based on this flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$('#tbl1').append($('#trHeader').remove());
```

Update,  I'm not sure where your button is to do the toggling, I'm going to assume that your toggling when you click the header row.  If otherwise, let me know.

```
$('#trHeader').toggle(function() {
  $('#tbl1').append($(this).remove());
}, function() {
  $('#tbl2').append($(this).remove());
});
```

Comment: I would like to toggle between appending and removing. How would I do that?

Comment: What if I want to take a row from Table1 and insert it in between two other rows in Table2?