# Remove row from one table and add it to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to remove a row from one table and add it to another with jQuery. I've examined [this similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702551/moving-table-row-from-one-table-to-the-other-using-jquery) and feel like I am doing roughly the same thing but am obviously missing something as what I am doing is not working. I know I've got the right row as the remove is working but the row is not being added to the new table.

jQuery

```
var row = $($.fn.colorbox.element()).parents('tr');
row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#NewTableBody').append(row.remove());
});
```

Table Body

```
<tbody id="NewTableBody">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only looking to remove and append a single row you can try the closest() traversal function:

```
var $row = $($.fn.colorbox.element()).closest('tr');
$row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#NewTableBody').append($row);
    $row.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

**Also your row is hidden (because of the fade out).  You need to show it again.**

Comment: Ah nice catch, didn't even think about it.

Comment: How to add one column additionally in row

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the remove() call, That is removing it from the DOM completely. append() will do the move for you.

```
var row = $($.fn.colorbox.element()).parents('tr');
row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#NewTableBody').append(row);
});
```

Comment: same answer at the (almost) same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The fadeout still occurs but the row is not appended to the `NewTableBody`.

Comment: Without seeing a link to test it would be hard to tell you what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var row = $($.fn.colorbox.element()).parents('tr');

row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#NewTableBody').append(row);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The fadeout still occurs but the row is not appended to the `NewTableBody`.